# Create a ListView with Dynamically generated Actions

Tags: android

Right now I have two activities. My goal is to allow the user to type something in on the first activity and click submit. It then uses search query on a site and pulls in the json object. Right now I have it listing the names within the jsonarray. What I want to allow the user to do is click on one of these items in the list, and the app will go fetch more detailed information from a different URL.

What is the best way to accomplish this? I already have the search box working, the linked list generating with the names I need, and also have the onclicklistener for each list item. How can I enable my app to go fetch something more detailed depending on what they click? The information needed to go fetch something is dependent on either what the specific list item says or if I can somehow embed a different action for each list item when it is dynamically created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using onClickListener you should use OnItemSelectedListener  then in

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View v, int position, long row) {

//you are given the position in the adapterview for the selected item here.  get it and do something
//like 
Intent yourIntent=new Intent(Context, YourOtherAcitivty.class);
yourIntent.putExtra("something",YourObjectArray.get(position));
startActivityForResult(yourIntent,0);

 //OR

yourMethodToGetMoreData(position);


//etc...
}
```

Comment: So essentially you are suggesting that I should create an array for each list item? Then when someone clicks it I fetch the necessary data from the array?

Comment: Well you have a ListView already (at least thats what i understood from your title).  Use whatever array you are using to populate the listview.  You don't need a an array for each list item - the item itself should already be an item of the array populating the listview.

Comment: My goal is to do this: Display a name from this array, but hide the necessary information to receive the specific item information on the click. I was wondering if there was a way to do that.

Comment: So create a class to hold your data like public class BananaBunches{ private int numBananas=0;private String supplier=null; private int ripeness=0; public void setNumBananas(int n) { numBananas=n;} public int getNumBananas() {return numBananas;} etc... bind  your listview to an arrayAdapter<BananaBunches>.  in your custom listadapter, set the textView of your listview to the number of bananas for example.  but don't display supplier.  in the onItemSelected do yourIntent.putExtra("supplier",YourArray.getPosition(position).getSupplier());

Comment: ah. i was thinking about doing that when I initially started making my app, but completely forgot about it! thanks!

Comment: How do I accomplish "in your custom listadapter, set the textView of your listview to the number of bananas for example. but don't display supplier."

Also, I am using an LinkedList<ListItem>, how do I add the various fields, i.e. name, date to each ListItem once I have pulled it from online

Comment: I figured the above out, but how can I make each action be different when a user clicks on an item?